Why do transaction go first to an RPC node before a validator
I have read from blogs and writings on the lifecycle of a transaction on the solana network, that a transaction after it creation in the DApp, is first sent to the RPC node, which then forwards the transaction to the validator node, my question here is, why do we need the RPC node stage, I want to understand the rational and use of the RPC node in the transaction lifecycle.

https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/924/can-i-send-rpc-requests-directly-to-a-validator Does this provide any hint to your question?

@AsaboroDaniel it has given me some more context to the need for RPC nodes, Thank you much
